# "Message/letter was read?" - Sentence help!

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, punctuation, direct-speech

I am writing an essay and it needs to be in formal language, I am referring to a letter/message and I am supposed to quote it for the readers, but before jumping right into quoting that letter, I like to make an introducing comment like, "The letter was read as follows," I know I'm confusing "is as follows" into it, but I like to have it in the same shade, just grammatical and perhaps formal.

Like, "The message was read as.."

Can someone with a better understanding of the English language and its idioms help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two common ways to write it.

> The message read: "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch . . . ."

Or

> The message read as follows: "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch . . . ."

Comment: *read**s*** perhaps too?

Comment: Surprisingly, I think both *read* and *reads* are possible and acceptable.

Comment: Agreed. I was just following the OP's example with the past simple. It could also be *had read, used to read, will read . . . .* Past simple is most common for  relating a story (narrating past events).